# PHP SQLSRV OUTPUT PARAMETER failed to return

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

Stored Procedure

```
USE [testtbl]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sptest]

@LeadID Bigint out
AS
insert into Lead (Name) values('test');
select @LeadID =@@IDENTITY;
```

//stored procedure

```
<?php

$arraysql(array($_POST[],SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT));

  $objFilter=new Filter();
  $spCall="{call dbo.sptest(?)}";
  $objFilter->InsertQuery($spCall,$arraysql);
?>

<?php
function InsertQuery($spCall,$parameter){
        $serverName = ".";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"php","UID"=>"","PWD"=>"");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if(!$conn){

            echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            sqlsrv_close($conn);
        }
        $resource=sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $spCall, $parameter);

        sqlsrv_next_result($resource);
        sqlsrv_fetch($resource);


         //resqlsrv_get_field($resource,0);
       // sqlsrv_close($conn);
     }
?>
```

i didn't paste everything coz its to long, so how to get the return value from the LeadID?
anyway do i need to declare the array to send it to insert query?
i tried it but i still didnt get the LeadID

Comment: You should add `sqlsrv_execute($resource);` before `sqlsrv_next_result($resource);` to execute your prepared statement.

Comment: hi i got an output Resource id #2, what do i need to do to get the id?

Comment: Did you uncommented `sqlsrv_get_field($resource,0);`?

Comment: no do i need to uncomment that?

Comment: yes, `sqlsrv_fetch()` makes resultset available for reading. `sqlsrv_get_field($resource,0);` will result what you tried to get.

Comment: i change the sp @identity into select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as 'id'; and also i remove the $arraysql since ill get the return id inside of the sp

Comment: $resource=sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $spCall, $parameter);
        $a=sqlsrv_execute($resource);
        $test=sqlsrv_get_field($a,0);

Comment: In conclusion, `$resource = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $spCall, $parameter);` `sqlsrv_execute($resource);` `sqlsrv_next_result($resource);` `sqlsrv_fetch($resource);` `$test = sqlsrv_get_field($resource,0);` should work.

Comment: it returned false here  $test = sqlsrv_get_field($resource,0);

Comment: hi i already did it, i just change the code into sqlsrv_qeury and sqlsrv_fetch_array